# Sort even indices of array by modifying merge sort in c

Tags: c, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I have a question where we need to sort only the even indices of an array using divide and conquer.
[image: question]

What I tried was modifying the original `mergeSort` function such that it will sort the even elements of subarrays. But in the merge sort function, we won't get every single element as we wouldn't know where to place if we get a single element, thus I made it so that base cases are when the subarray is of size 3 or 4. it will sort the subarray, but in a way that the even index in term of even index of main array only is sorted, thus line x.
The result I got was that the odd elements were untouched, but the even elements were not sorted correctly.
[image: output]
below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r);
void mergeSort(int arr[], int si, int ei);

int main() {
    int num;
    
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int arr[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    
    mergeSort(arr, 0, num - 1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int si, int ei) {
    if ((ei - si == 2) && (si % 2 == 0)) {
        if (arr[si] > arr[si + 2]) {
            int temp = arr[si];
            arr[si] = arr[si + 2];
            arr[si + 2] = arr[si];
        }
    }                                     //base case 1
    
    if ((ei - si == 3)) {
        int x = (si % 2 == 0) ? si : si + 1;      //line x
        if (arr[x] > arr[x + 2]) {
            int temp = arr[x];
            arr[x] = arr[x + 2];
            arr[x + 2] = arr[x];
        }                                 //base case 2
    }
    if (si < ei) {
        int mid = si + (ei - si) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, si, mid);             //calling merge sort on both the halves of array
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, ei);
        
        merge(arr, si, mid, ei);
    }
}

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;
 
    int arr1[n1], arr2[n2];
 
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        arr1[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        arr2[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i = i + 2) {
        arr[i] = arr1[i];
    }
    i = (n1 % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1;
    for (;i < n2; i = i + 2) {
        arr[i+n1] = arr2[i];
    }
    
    i = 0;
    j = (n1 % 2 == 0) ? 0 : 1, k = l;
    
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = arr1[i];
        k = k + 2;
        i = i + 2;
    }
    
    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k++] = arr2[j];
        k = k + 2;
        j = j + 2;
    }
    
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = arr1[i];
        k = k + 2;
        i = i + 2;
    }
    
    while (j < n2) {
        arr[k] = arr2[j];
        k = k + 2;
        j = j + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: if `num` is an odd number, add a 0 to the end of the array so that the array length is always an even number. And then only divide the array into subarrays of even lengths. For example, if `n` is 9, create an array of length 10, and put a zero in the last position. Then, when dividing the array of length 10, don't split it into arrays of length 5. Instead split it into an array of length 6, and an array of length 4.

Comment: Naive thought: create a new array containing the even indices. Run a normal unmodified mergesort on it, then populate those values back into the even indices of the original array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the loop `for (int i = 0; i < n1; i = i + 2) { arr[i] = arr1[i]; }` is incorrect because you should use `arr[l + i]` instead of `arr[i]` but even corrected, it would still be useless: just ignore the elements at even indices.
- note also that even indices in a recursive call are not necessarily even indices in the original arrays because you compute `int mid = si + (ei - si) / 2;` which may produce an odd value.
- you make special cases of slices of length 3 and 4 but the problem is in splitting the array with an odd left slice length.
- using the convention with inclusive upper bounds leads to complicated code with error prone `+1`/`-1` adjustments.  It is simpler in C to use excluded upper bounds.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge(int arr[], int lo, int mid, int hi); // hi is excluded
void mergeSort(int arr[], int lo, int hi);  // hi is excluded

int main(void) {
    int num;
    
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num <= 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        int arr[num];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    
        mergeSort(arr, 0, num);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi - lo > 2) {
        // split the array with an even length for the left slice
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo + 1) / 4 * 2;
        mergeSort(arr, lo, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid, hi);
        merge(arr, lo, mid, hi);
    }
}

void merge(int arr[], int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = (mid - lo) / 2;
    int arr1[n1];
 
    // save the elements at even index values in the left slice
    for (i = 0, j = lo; i < n1; i++, j += 2) {
        arr1[i] = arr[j];
    }

    // merge the slices, using only elements at even index values
    for (i = 0, j = mid, k = lo; i < n1 && j < hi; k += 2) {
        if (arr1[i] <= arr[j]) {
            arr[k] = arr1[i];
            i += 1;
        } else {
            arr[k] = arr[j];
            j += 2;
        }
    }
    // copy remaining elements from left slice
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[k] = arr1[i];
        k += 2;
        i += 1;
    }
    // remaining elements from right slice are already in their final places
}
```

Output:

```
chqrlie$ ./230902-sorteven
11
7 1 3 24 34 53 2 56 7 7 8
2 1 3 24 7 53 7 56 8 7 34
```

Comment: Tough crowd today... Informative, correct answer with code meticulously formatted and commented ... and no upvotes??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: yep, slow Saturday. I should do some real work, like proofreading a 53 page SHA.